# Sorting wordpress post by custom date field where custom date field > current date

Tags: wordpress

How can I get in WordPress 6 posts, ordered by custom date field and wich have this custom date field > or = with current date. And how should I enter that `custom_date`? (what format).

EDIT: I try to do something like this:

```
$argsq = array(
          'cat' => 6,   
          'showposts' => 6,
          'meta_key'     => 'data-spectacol',
          'meta_value'   => date( "d-m-Y" ), 
          'meta_compare' => '>',
        );
```

And insert the `data-spectacol` meta field in a `d-m-Y` format in WordPress (like `15-5-2016`) but i get older posts to, not only the posts after current date..

Comment: I suggest you start by looking at [the examples here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: Followed by [this section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: I read those, however i didnt manage to do it.

Comment: `d-m-Y` is not practical for sorting. `Y-m-d` works when using date and string functions for comparison. unix timestamps are also practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$args = array(
    // the number of posts to show
    'showposts' => '6',
    // filter the posts with the date
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'data-spectacol',
        'value'   => date( "Y-m-d" ), // change to how the date is stored
        'compare' => '>',
        'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    // sort by the date field
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'data-spectacol',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Make sure that the date is in a format that can be sorted correctly, this is usually done with `Y-m-d` or something similar.